# Nested Linear Layouts not working propely

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, nested

Here's the xml code, I'm trying to have nested linear Layouts, one external being vertical and one internal being horizontal. I'm not sure why Android Studio is understanding the external as being closed by the closing tag of the internal, and the internal as being closed by the external.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:id="@+id/quantity_title" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"


            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:onClick="increment"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
                android:text="0"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:onClick="decrement"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:id="@+id/price_title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
            android:text="$0"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/price_title"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:I'm new to xml, I didn't know whether it was a xml thing. It's a closing tag. Sorry for the simple mistake.

Comment: You forgot to close a LinearLayout and a TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten the closing tag

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

and also the same for Textview

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:text="0"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Linerlayout support only horizontal and vertical allignment of view.If orientation is vertical then all views will align vertically but orientaion is horizontal then views will be allign horizontally.
In your case inside Second Linerlayout ,the Textview  should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

watch the tags PLZ !!
please read about xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:id="@+id/quantity_title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="increment"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:text="0"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:onClick="decrement"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:id="@+id/price_title" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
        android:text="$0"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/price_title"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Order"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
</LinearLayout>
```